# Issue with linking CNAME in Laravel with wildcard subdomains

Tags: laravel, apache, dns, cname

I'm trying to make a Laravel application that people can sign up to my Laravel app and then a subdomain will be created dynamically for each user.

```
Route::group([
                'domain' => {account}.mylaravelapp.example',
                'middleware' => 'Authorize'
            ], function () {

                Route::get('/', function ($account) {
                    return $account;
                });
            });
```

So if a user register an account and set the account name as `test` then they will have a subdomain created at `test.mylaravelapp.example`. This subdomain returns a view with data related to their account.

I'd like to give users the ability to mirror their site at `test.mylaravelapp.example` to their own domain address. I tried to mirror by updating the `CNAME` record to `test.mylaravelapp.example` for my domain and `A` record to the  `test.mylaravelapp.example` IP address, however it does not seem to work.

It is always redirecting me to default webpage.cgi

```
test.example/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
```

So now I'm left wondering how I can point requests in the right direction when they land on my application. So for example if traffic hits `random.example` and it has an `A` record that is equal to my servers IP, plus a `CNAME` of `test.mylaravelapp.example`, then how do I handle the request and redirect it to the correct subdomain whilst keeping the user on their custom domain?

Comment: Not sure to understand the question but about *it has an A record that is equal to my servers IP, plus a CNAME of test.mylaravelapp.example*: this is not possible you can not have at the same time a `CNAME` and an `A` record on the same label, the CNAME presence forbids any other one.

Comment: A records to parent domain and CNAME for subdomain